# Laravel : json encode returns empty in DB update

Tags: json, laravel

When I use json_encode in the update query builder of laravel, it returns empty. The code I tried was this:

```
    DB::table('catalog_product')->update([
        'reference' => json_encode(['data' =>DB::raw('external_barcode')]),
    ]);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? Can you also give a little bit more information about the table e.g. what is `reference`, what is `external_barcode`? etc.

Comment: @RossWilson I thought it was self explainatory. I'm trying to move the data in one column to another in json format

Comment: You are mixing PHP and MYSQL update, this cannot work. You can use pure PHP and get all your records from your table, then loop and update with `json_encode()` function, or use `JSON_OBJECT` function in mysql. But you'll need key / value to encode a value.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I have updated the code in question for key value pair. How do I use the json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, you are mixing a PHP function with a MYSQL value.

Or you use the PHP way :

```
$products = CatalogProduct::get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
   $product->reference = json_encode(['data' => $product->external_barcode]);
   $product->save();
}
```

Or using MYSQL :

```
DB::table('catalog_product')->update([
    'reference' => DB::raw('JSON_OBJECT("data", external_barcode)'),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd method was what I needed

Comment: Accept the answer if your problem is solved. Thanks